# Should WeakReference to a Context object be used when instantiating a Loader/AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-loadermanager, android-loader

I came across information that a WeakReference to the Context object should be used with AsyncTasks and Loaders to avoid memory leaks in case Activity gets destroyed before the AsyncTask completes. But i am unclear if any references to the Context should be a weak reference - including the one when a AsyncTask gets instantiated. So should, say, AsyncTaskLoader be instantiated this way?

```
public abstract class BaseLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<Response> {

    public BaseLoader(WeakReference<Context> context){
        super(context.get());
    }

    ...
}
```

Or is it fine to user the actual Context object to instantiate the AsyncTastkLoader class, but keep a WeakReference to context in case it is needed anywhere else in the AsyncTask?

Comment: It is probably a bad idea. If you keep a reference to a context is because your probably want to access resources. How do you act if it is garbage collected ?

Comment: My understanding is that once the object is garbage collected it becomes null. So a null check is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't help you here because you're going to pass the context to super().  If the super function is storing it, its going to be responsible for its own weak referencing of it (or not).  This only applies to cases where you store the context long term.